# Symfony2 Assetic Generate URLs pointing to CDN

Tags: symfony, cdn, assetic

Is there a way I can extend Assetic so it will allow me to have it load my images from a CDN which I configure somewhere else. If I can write a plugin/extension/event listener/etc which allows fine-grain control, that would be awesome.

Likewise, are there any hooks for the assetic:dump console command which I could use so when I perform a dump I can automatically push images from the local box to the CDN (since I want the images to load locally on dev)?

Basically, I want to be able to have an images sitting somewhere in on my local machine, say:
web/images/image.png

On dev, when I do something like:

```
asset('images/image.png')
```

It would spit out a URL like this on dev:

```
http://1.2.3.4/images/image.png
```

And on production it'd spit out something like:

```
http://my.cdn.net/images/image.png
```

And when I run assetic:dump, the image is automatically uploaded.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out this link: http://symfony.com/doc/master/reference/configuration/framework.html#assets-base-urls

You can add a base url in your config.yml like:

```
framework:
    templating:      
        assets_base_urls:
            http: my.cdn.net
```

Comment: Sorry for the slow reply. That looks like it might do the trick, or at the very least point me in the proper direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Since Symfony 2.7, configuration has changed:

```
framework:
    assets:
        base_urls:
          - 'http://cdn.example.com/'
```

check out :
http://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-2-7-the-new-asset-component